# If $L\in REG$ then $M$ has a finite number of distinct rows

Tags: computability, automata, regular-language

Let $L \subseteq \Sigma^{\star}$ and let $M^{\Sigma^{\star} \times \Sigma^{\star}}(\{0,1\})$ an infinite matrix such that for each $x,y\in \Sigma^\star$:
$$
m_{x,y}=\begin{cases}
1 & x y\in L\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I need to show that if $L\in REG$ then there is a finite number of distinct rows in $M$.

$M$ rows resemble me of binary representations of real numbers in $[0,1]$ so perhaps I need to find a function $f:M_i \to [0,1] $ and conclude that since a regular language  has a cardinality of  $\aleph_0$ there can be only a finite number of distinct rows, but:

- I don't know if that is really the direction to prove this claim.
- I can't find such an $f$. Furthermore, what if $M$'s rows are the unit vectors? There are infinite many distinct rows but the similarity to real numbers binary representation is no longer intuitive to me.

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how were you hoping to get finiteness out of your suggested approach?  I don't really see how you would.  You definitely need to use a much stronger property of regular languages than countability!

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you. It's only the second week we study this material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem): the rows for $x$ and $y$ are identical if and only if for all $z\in\Sigma^*$, $xz\in L$ iff $yz\in L$ iff there is no distinguishing extension for $x$ and $y$. There is a proof of the theorem at the link, but you might want to try to find one yourself from this HINT: the number of distinct rows is equal to the number of states in the smallest DFA recognizing $L$. (In other words, think in terms of the operation of a DFA recognizing $L$.)

Comment: Let me know if I should remove my answer.  I thought of writing it before I saw your answer, and now I'm not sure if I gave too strong a hint.

Comment: @Tara: No, leave it; my hint was pretty minimal.

Comment: Thanks Brian and Tara. Your hints were quite helpful and I understood it.

Comment: @Amihai: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Amihai:  Glad to hear it was helpful.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Let $A$ be a deterministic finite state automaton accepting $L$.  For a fixed $x\in \Sigma^*$, the value of $m_{x,y}$ depends only on the state the automaton $A$ is in after reading $x$ (beginning in the initial state).

(Oh dear, I just read Brian's answer and it looks like we have given complementary hints!)